# Laptop wear with temperatures under control

Tags: laptop, temperature

I have a thin laptop (Asus ZenBook 14 if you wonder) and I feel relatively concerned about the wear rate of my pc due to heating. In fact, while I use medium-to-high demand software my laptop reaches temperatures like 65 Celsius for the cpu (8th gen i7) and 55 for the gpu (nvidia mx150) (both checked with throttlestop, with which I also performed a subtle undervolting of the cpu for this matter). The problem is that whenever I touch the pc to move it or just to check the desk temp (my desk is made of wood, if that matters) it feels really hot, so hot that it would be uncomfortable to hold it e.g. on my lap. Is this thing a problem, or should I just look at the actual p.u. temps and be happy? As far as I now the cpu and the gpu are fine in those temperatures, but maybe other components are suffering from this condition. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did the undervolting cause issues? My laptop is 1/2 inch thick with i7 CPU and tons of software. It runs quite cool.  Can you set the CPU back to default and see what happens?

Comment: Be sure you are not blocking the fan vents if it has any.

Comment: You have not been able to put a laptop in your actual lap for over a decade.  Unless you have experienced thermal throttling then your device is running as it was designed.  If you have never killed the family of dust bunnies that live in your device, that might help, but given the temperatures they are well below the maximum temperatures for your device.

Comment: "You have not been able to put a laptop in your actual lap for over a decade."   I use my laptop on my lap frequently and for hours at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! John: well actually the situation is basically the same as before the undervolting, the tempreatures reported are a bit lower on average, but I cannot feel a difference by touching it. Actually I should point it out that this heating comes mostly when playing games, so maybe the heat is due to air coming from the gpu. Moab: well the pc is on a completely flat surface, with no near objects or heat sources. Ramhound: of course the lap thing was just an example to underline the heat that the pc surface is facing. I have never fallen in throttling in my use cases so far

Comment: What is the case temperature (bottom case cover)?  I have two laptops here - 1 with SSD and i7 CPU the other with HDD and i5 CPU. Case temperature of both machines on the bottom side and averaging the readings is 30 degrees C

Comment: At the moment i have no efficient way of measuring the temp accurately, but I can tell you that this laptop runs cool when browsing only (I assume 30 degrees, or lower probably), while in the situation i am depicting it is not that far from the 55 degrees of the gpu: now that i think about it maybe that the gpu is placed really just above the lower case, and that is why I feel the heat so strongly. Still, I am not sure that this is healthy for the rest of the components, since all that heat is also spreading through the desk, in fact also the woos gets incomfortably warm.

Comment: Whether the other components can take the heat is a matter of design. We cannot help with that. I have stuff in the basement that runs hot but it was designed to do this. Computers are happier with an overall operating temperature under 40 degree C.

Comment: Thank you John. I'll try to keep it under 40 in the future

Comment: What's the exact CPU model? If we know this we can look at its tdp (thermal design point) and advise better.

Comment: Hi davidgo, sure: it's an **i7-8565U**. For completeness, I state again that the gpu is an MX150. Thank you